# Mac Automater: from a string, get a file

Tags: service, applescript, workflow, automator, finder

I'm trying to make a shortcut via an automater service that will move the selected file(s) up a directory. It goes as follows:

1. Get Selected Finder Items
2. Get Value of Variable `Path`
3. Run Applescript:

   ```
   on join(someList, delimiter)
   set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
       set output to "" & someList
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
       return output
   end join
   to split(someText, delimiter)
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
       set someText to someText's text items
       set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
       return someText
   end split
   on run {input, parameters}
       set pathToMe to POSIX path of (item 1 of input as text)
       set newPath to split(pathToMe, "/")
       set revPath to reverse of newPath
       set restList to rest of revPath
       set restList to rest of restList
       set joinPath to join(reverse of restList, "/")
       set source to POSIX file joinPath
       return source
   end run
   ```
4. Set Value of Variable `Parent`
5. Move Finder Items To `Parent`

The Applescript parses the first file path in the `Path` in order to find the item's grandparent, returning it as a POSIX file string. The problem is that the "Move Finder" action only accepts Files/Folders. How can I select the target parent folder with the resulting string in order to pass it to the "Move Finder" action?

Things I've tried:

- Using `mv` in a `Run Bash Script`: the `Run Applescript` action doesn't seem to return anything to the `Run Bash Script`; set to input as arguments, "$@" is always empty.
- Doing a `tell finder` in `Run Applescript`. No error or warning, just nothing happens.
- Manually setting the value of the `parent` variable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return a path of type `alias` in a **list** instead of a `posix file`

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set pathToMe to (item 1 of input) as text
    set f to my getParent(pathToMe, ":")
    return {f as alias}
end run

to getParent(someText, delimiter)
    set prevTIDs to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
    set n to -2
    if someText ends with ":" then set n to -3
    set t to text 1 thru text item n of someText
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to prevTIDs
    return t
end getParent
```

Comment: the getParent didn't work for some reason, it looks like it should, but the idea to return an alias instead was right on the money

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this all in applescript so try this code. I didn't test it but it should work. You can still add this to automator with an applescript action but you don't need all the other actions. It will do everything itself. Good luck.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theSelection to get selection
    set parentFolder to container of (item 1 of theSelection)
    move theSelection to parentFolder
end tell
```

Comment: doesn't work, tried from the context menu and with get selected/specified/ask for finder items, service is set to accept files or folders as input. error is "can't get item 1 of {}". thoughts?

Comment: It works for me. Run it as an applescript right from Script Editor instead of Automator. Select some files in a Finder window and then run the script. So since it works then we know the problem is with how you are implementing it in automator... which is something you'll have to figure out. My advice was to not use any automator actions in addition to this code but it seems you have done that and thus it isn't implemented properly.

Comment: Now that I know it exists I will happily do this stuff in the script editor from now on =] automator is a pain but I didn't know of another way.
However, this still didn't work. Ran the script with files selected, the output showed what was selected but nothing moved.
Assuming I'm doing something wrong, how would I use this as a service in the context menu? Just put it in library/services?